# How to setup VPS to forward multiple IPs to a single static IP

Tags: vpn, ip, vps, forwarding, cryptomining

Im running a bunch of crypto masternodes and I have a vpn so I can get a static IP for my local server machines (I have to do this because Im on cable internet which doesnt allow me to purchase static IPs).

Currently if I want to run multiple masternodes of the same coin, I will have to purchase multiple VPN accounts, each with their own separate static IP. This isnt ideal because I want to have lots of masternodes of the same coin going forwards.

Im thinking of a possible solution but Im not sure how easy this is to set up, or if its even feasible. Is there a way to purchase a single VPS service, and somehow add multiple static IPs to it, and then route all traffic it receives to any of those IPs it controls to my home networks static IP, perhaps with some kind of identifying information so my home network can work out which static IP it came from and send the request to the relevant masternode machine?

Also if I could set something up like this, how much of the VPS CPU/RAM would be used, if all the VPS was doing was basically forwarding all traffic it received to a different IP?

I hope this kind of makes sense, any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with basic Dynamic DNS and port forwarding?

Comment: "_how much of the VPS CPU/RAM would be used?_" - impossible to say without knowing what sort of bandwidth you're talking about...

Comment: What exactly is the use of multiple masternodes? I somewhat suspect the 1-node-per-IP restriction is there _specifically_ to make it harder to do what you're trying to do...

Comment: i have enough coins to be hosting multiple masternodes of the same coin.

i dont understand why the 1 node per IP restriction is designed to stop people from hosting multiple? its easy enough to just spin up a bunch of cheap cloud vps, each with their own static ip, and host as many masternodes as you want, for around 5 bucks a month per vps...

the difference is i want to host the masternodes on my own hardware, which in my opinion is better than relying on a vps.

the only reason i cant do this easily is cause im on cable (no static ips)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to purchase a single VPS service, and somehow add multiple static IPs to it

Yes, as long as your VPS hosting company offers this service. Usually extra IPv4 addresses come at a cost due to shortage.

> and then route all traffic it receives to any of those IPs it controls to my home networks static IP

Yes, that's essentially just a VPN.

> perhaps with some kind of identifying information so my home network can work out which static IP it came from

Yes – don't use DNAT and don't assign the IP addresses to the VPN server itself, but instead assign them to your home LAN's router, or maybe even directly to machines on your home LAN.

Then configure routing on the VPS so that it knows where to forward packets for those addresses (i.e. via your VPN). Additionally, the VPS will likely need to run proxy-ARP for those addresses, e.g. via `parpd`.

> if I could set something up like this, how much of the VPS CPU/RAM would be used, if all the VPS was doing was basically forwarding all traffic it received to a different IP?

It's all in the CPU (unless you get into the business of BGP peering), but if your regular traffic is below 100 Mbps, then you probably won't even notice the load at all. (How much CPU does your own computer use while running a network speedtest?)

Comment: OK I have vultr VPS instance to test this on, its running Ubuntu. Im struggling to work out what to install/setup on the VPS to route all traffic pointing to its static IP + some arbitrary port, to go to my home networks static public IP... is this something should use `iptables` for? Or is there something better for Ubuntu?

Comment: Set up a VPN as the first thing. OpenVPN, ocserv/openconnect, ZeroTier, Wireguard, whichever you prefer.

Comment: install OpenVPN on my Ubuntu VPS? I thought I didnt need the security of VPN tunneling? I just want to do a plain old redirect/forward?

Comment: Making a virtual network is the whole point of a VPN; the security is an optional extra.

Comment: The point is that packets from the VPS are much more restricted when crossing many hops across the internet – the source address of forwarded packets cannot be preserved (anti-spoofing protection), and so on. You can think of various workarounds (including GRE or IPIP tunnels), but using existing VPN software is the simplest one.